# Price location on product page

Tags: price

Our product price is down near the add to cart button but I would like it up by the sku. Is there an easy way to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

In your local.xml file of your template:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
   <catalog_product_view>
       <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <block>product.clone_prices</block>
            </action>
       </reference>
       <reference name="product.info">
          <action method="insert">
              <block>product.clone_prices</block>
          </action>
       </reference>
   </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

This unsets the block from the product info options wrapper and places it at the top of the product info block.  This may or may not give you what you want, depending on how you want it styled and located.

You can also call it in your template file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('prices')->toHtml(); ?>
```

You can also create a new instance of it in the layout and call it through `getChildHtml();`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
            <block type="catalog/product_price" name="custom.location.price" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Now call it in your .phtml file like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom.location.price'); ?>
```